# Chrome returns "SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, jquery

OK, this question has been queried quite frequently and in many variations, but STILL I haven't found any answer that would redeem me from this torture.

My code works fine with Safari, Internet Explorer v.8. However, Chrome throws the "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" message - only in specific combinations (it's about chained 's).

The following is a JSON I return from an ASP (classic) page. It works on 99% of the inputs, but for the following JSON text, it throws the error:

```
{"queryStatus":"Not_Empty", "printID":["50674","54648","50437","37564","37566","37565","49124","null"], "printName":["BBB-12312313","BBB-1558","BBB-2-065 + 2-066","BBB-2-217","BBB-2-217b","BBB-2-226/2-217b ","BBB-2-5961b","null"]}
```

Now, my JS code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "callbacks/xmlHTTPRequestGetPrintItems.asp?LabelID=" + $("#LicenseLabel").val() + "&RequestType=0",
                    data: "",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (data.queryStatus == "Not_Empty") {
                            for (i = 0; i < data.printID.length - 1; i++) {
                                $('#ApprovalItem').append($('<option>', { value: data.printID[i] }).text(data.printName[i]));
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(thrownError); }
});
```

Result: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Here's what I've tried:

1. Changing the "contentType"/removing it, both the $.ajax option and the server side page's response;
2. Looking for special characters - nothing;
3. Pulling out the "null" strings at the end of the object;

I have read about the zero-width-spacing which I might be retrieving from the database (Unicode-200B, perhaps?), but I haven't managed to resolve it just yet.

AGAIN - it works on Chrome for 99% of the inputs, and on IE 8 it works on 100%.
Assistance would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Is the error in the console or is it the alert that shows it?

Comment: The error is alerted. The ASP file returns the mentioned JSON text, which would for all other cases except for this one.

Comment: If it's the alert that's being shown then that means the ajax call caused an error on the server - it's nothing to do with what's being returned.  That sounds very strange considering it works on other browsers.

Comment: It is strange, isn't it? I mean, it even works on Chrome for every other value that's chosen in the parent <select>. Only one specific value from the parent select, which returns the mentioned JSON populates this error.

Comment: Is the return in your post the actual return that you get from the call that causes the error?

Comment: It is. I'm suspecting that the original SELECT I use retrieves a "zero-width-space", however I couldn't track it down. Have you handled anything similar before?

Comment: It may benefit you to you a low-level sniffer like WireShark to look at the raw byte-level response. That would make any suspected unusual characters easier to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not work.  I can't reproduce the issue with the above information, which obviously makes it difficult to help you, but this would be my first suggestion...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "callbacks/xmlHTTPRequestGetPrintItems.asp?LabelID=" + $("#LicenseLabel").val() + "&RequestType=0",
    data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text",
    async: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        if (data.queryStatus == "Not_Empty") {
            for (i = 0; i < data.printID.length - 1; i++) {
                $('#ApprovalItem').append($('<option>', { value: data.printID[i] }).text(data.printName[i]));
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(thrownError); }
});
```

All I've done is specify the dataType as text, rather than JSON, and then used `JSON.parse()` when it's returned.  It will at least determine if the error is the call or the response (but I think we already know that).

Comment: Thanks Archer - that was helpful. It now does actually access the "success" method, however the same error is being reproduced and discovered when debugging with Chrome. I will try to go deeper into the DB output and see if something's fishy there.

Comment: @pushplaybang - yes, sorry for the hold up. The resolution was achieved by combining the change of the "dataType" option within the ajax calls along with replacing TABS with SPACES on the callback server page (just using your server-side language replace() method  equivalent).

Comment: Thanks, seems I only get this if my server side validation fails, so must be something in my return values on failure along these lines.